# Dragging text around in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop

First time posting, so thanks for any help - great site here! I'm new to iPhone programming and am wondering how best to approach this problem:

I have a background image and I'd like to place text on the image and let the user drag the text around on the image. Nothing fancy, really, but I'm not sure I am approaching it right (there's **lots** of ways to doing things in iOS :-) ).

Here's what I've done:

1. I created a custom view controller for the background image and replaced the view in the controller with a UIScrollView.
2. I added a UIImageView to the scroll view and selected the desired image. The background works fine - I can drag the image around and it animates with scroll bars, etc.

3, I then added a regular ol' UIView onto the background view. (I'm doing this in IB, BTW) and it just sits there in the same spot on the background, looking dumb while the background moves around.

So is this the right approach for what I want to do? I know I need to customize the "touches" methods, and I've fiddle with that a bit, but I'm not even sure where the code should go. In the background controller? Or do I create a controller for the text view?

I didn't post any code as I'd first like to understand how a "guru" would approach this, then I can hunt down some specific examples.

Thanks!

-David

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Touches sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks ibeitia. What I'm trying to is a bit more complicated - I'm using a view controller, and that's what's confusing me. Maybe I don't need one?